# How do I display database data in table format?

Tags: ruby

I want to display the table in the below format. How can I achieve this?

```
  ---A----+-----B-----+----C-----
   12335   |  abcd     |  qwerty
   45335   |  efgh     |  poiuy
   78956   |  hjukukuk |  mkloijhkll
   12346   |  sfsfsf   |  vbhkhadad
```

EDIT 1: 
The contents of the table can be of any length. The width of the particular cell has to be decided by the content itself.

I got the column width from

col_width = a.transpose.map{|col| col.map{|cell| cell.to_s.length}.max}

and displayed the table contents with:
a.each{|row| puts '['+
 row.zip(col_width).map{|cell, w| cell.to_s.ljust(w)}.join(' | ')+']'}

where 'a' contains the data from the database.

I only cannot get to print the column headers.

How i can achieve those so that it can align with the table cell contents.

I need to display the output in the console. I am using OCI for accessing the database.

Comment: What have you tried? How do you intend to connect to the database?  Are you using an ORM adapter (ActiveRecord, DataMapper, etc)?

Comment: What is the format of the data? What decides the width, etc.? Do you really want the `+` character not match the position of the `|` character in the following lines as in your edit (which you changed from mine)? Without that the question is unclear.

Comment: i have the data available from the database. width has to be decided by the contents itself.

Comment: It does not matter whether it is from a database or not. What matters is the format.

Comment: Please, be more clear. Do you want to display this format in console?

Comment: the + character if aligned to the | character will align the table properly.

Comment: yes i want to display the output in console

Answer (score 0):

The [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/) ORM can do this using the [pretty_table](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc-plugins/files/lib/sequel/extensions/pretty_table_rb.html) extension. Otherwise [HIRB](https://github.com/cldwalker/hirb) is capable of doing it, either with ActiveRecord, or from arrays/hashes.

I use Sequel often, and have occasional need to display a table summary on the console, so `pretty_table` works nicely for me.

HIRB is used in the [irbtools](https://github.com/janlelis/irbtools) plugin for IRB, and provides table output for all sorts of things.

In either case, the displayed table width is dynamically determined using the lengths of the strings being displayed to find the widths of the columns. I've never tried pushing really long strings through either that would require wrapping inside a column, but they should automatically handle that since it's a common requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a gem that will help you with this: http://github.com/arches/table_print